# How do I reset/remove a Windows 10 password on an external hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery

Seem to be having problems getting past the SEO-optimized "How to buy our program" sites on this one. I have a client with a Windows 10 PC where they use their password daily to login. No change of password but suddenly the computer isn't accepting it. I went on site and checked everything in the books that can be covered by: I used the "show password" eyeball to see that it was typed correctly, as they do every single day. I trust this client to not be one to make mistakes or tamper with anything on their own that shouldn't be.

I have the tower and currently have the HD on a dock on my own Windows 10 computer. Command prompt password resets seem to only work for the used system, even though I navigate to the external HD's System32. No other users on the system. Booted SAFE mode (previously, on site) and rebooted several times to no avail each time. Grabbed the hash from the SAM file and tried a NT hash generator with the password and all similar variations; so I know the saved password is actually different. I'd rather not wait for a brute force if there's a free way to just reset it without losing valuable data.

Comment: Did you rule out the possibility that the account has been upgraded from a local windows account to a Microsoft account? I know this can happen by logging in to certain Microsoft apps and not being vigilant about optional checkboxes in the login. (Teams can do this).

Comment: How do I check this without being able to login and what can be done?

Comment: Well the simplest thing to try would be to attempt to log in with Microsoft account credentials; If that works then that's what happened. I'm not sure how to tell if an account is an online or local account by inspecting the drive files alone. It needs to be booted and logged in with some kind of administrator access which will let you see details about the other users on the system.